# Can I publish an indie game on XBL made with directx

Tags: directx, xbox-live

So I know that XNA can be used to publish games on Xbox Live Indie Games and I signed up for the $100/year subscription thing.

I haven't downloaded XNA yet but I was wondering if I can publish a game made entirely in DirectX onto it or do I have to go through XNA?

Answer (score 2):

XNA is the only method for a consumer (such as your yourself) to get a game onto the 360, and it requires managed code.

Licensed developers can use native code toolchains, which provides access to an API much like Direct3D (but which isn't *exactly* Direct3D).

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Ammar should give it the green check.